# C# Regex to find strings surrounded by curly braces that do not have just a digit inside the braces

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

My problem is this.  I have some string formatting that I need to check for a very specific regex, and having trouble figuring out how to locate it properly (the correct regex).  For example, consider this string.

```
string str = "Hi {0} I {1} a string."
```

This then gets read by a `String.Format` as:

```
string formattedStr = String.Format(str,there, am);
```

Now consider:

```
"Hi {there} I {1} a string."
```

I would like to be able to locate {there} and escape it, as otherwise my `String.Format` will throw an error, as its trying to parameterize {there}, which doesn't work.

I figure I should look for strings that are 1)surrounded by curly braces that 2) have more than 1 character between them.  This way I will ignore anything like `{0}` or `{1}`, but not `{there}`, `{regex}`, etc.  Then I can escape them as needed, so that `String.Format` will not try to format them.  Thanks!

Comment: I had thrown in Regex.Replace(str, @"^(?=.{3}){([^[0-9]+)}", @"{{$1}}");  My understanding was that ^(?=.{3}) would check ahead to make sure the length of the string (including the braces) was 3 characters.  The latter part would then check what was contained within  the braces.  I guess though I would want to check for strings greater than 3 digits.  I am also aware that the above test would not work for a string that contained something like {there1}, but this would be easy enough to fix.  I guess my main difficulty is how to write proper regex syntax for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderestimating here, but wouldn't

```
\{\D+\}
```

do?

This translates to "An open curly-brace followed by one or more non-digits followed by a close curly-brace".

Comment: My understanding of regex syntax is poor, but let's see if I understand: this regex looks for  curly braces with any number of digits inside?  If so, I'd probably want something like \{\D+} to include normal characters.  I'm trying to select all those that aren't only numbers, but that are still included within the curly braces.  Something like \{[A-Za-z0-9]+\}?

Comment: Wow, so it really was that simple.  Guess I need to study regex more.  That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this Regex: `\{(\s*?.*?)*?\}`?

And then parse the contents of the groups to see if it is numerical? If it's not numerical then you're seeing what you're looking for. If it isn't numerical then you just append your escape to the beginning of the string.

Comment: I should state that I say check to see if the contents are numerical, because it could be possible that you have more than 10 parameters {10}, {11}, etc. Checking if they're numerical is a lot more reliable than only checking for a single digit.

Comment: This looks like it would have worked - I went with Tomas' answer as it was a lot shorter.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

To match any contents between curly braces, you may use `{[^{}]}` regex. So, in order to avoid matching any `{...}` strings with digits, all you need to do is to add a digit matching pattern into the `[^{}]` negated character class:

```
{[^{}\d]*}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cd%5D*%7D&i=%22Hi%20%7Bthere%7D%20I%20%7B1%7D%20a%20string.%22%20)

**Details**:

- `{` - a literal open `{`
- `[^{}\d]*` - zero or more (due to `*`, use `+` if you need 1 or more occurrences) characters other than `{`, `}` and digits (if you need to avoid matching only ASCII digits, replace with unambiguous `[0-9]`)
- `}` - a literal close `}`.

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/7U8v60) showing only `{there}` as output:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// ...

var s = "Hi {there} I {1} a string.";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, @"{[^{}\d]*}")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(p => p.Value)
    .ToList();
```

**BONUS:** If you need to extract only what is in-between `{...}`, add a capturing group to the pattern  - `@"{([^{}\d]*)}"` - and instead of `.Select(p => p.Value)` use `.Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)` in the code.